# WordPress query args if two values then

Tags: php, wordpress, arguments

Maybe it is a realy stupid question but I cant get my head around it. When I read the code it makes sense, it does what it does but I dont know how to change it to work properly. This is the query:

```
return array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'is_featured' => array(
                'key' => 'featured',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS'
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'pakket-of-dienst',
                'value'     => array('vps hosting'),
                'compare'   => 'IN',
            ),
        ),
        'orderby' => array(
            'is_featured' => 'DESC'
        )
    );
```

It selects all pages that have a pakket-of-dienst value of "vps hosting" and when a page exist with the key "featured" it will show this page too.

Problem is that there are multiple pakket-of-dienst values.

How can I make the query to only select pages where pakket-of-dienst is "vps hosting" and featured has value 0 or 1?

Problem now it that when pakket-of-dienst is "vps hosting" he also shows the featured pages of pakket-of-dienst is "webhosting".

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this :

```
return [
    'post_type'   => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query'  => [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'relation' => 'OR',
            [
                'key'   => 'featured',
                'value' => 1
            ],
            [
                'key'   => 'featured',
                'value' => 0
            ]
        ],
        [
            'key'   => 'pakket-of-dienst',
            'value' => 'vps hosting', //no need "in" as you check against one value only
        ],
    ],
    'orderby'     => [
        'is_featured' => 'DESC'
    ]
];
```

Note: I tend to avoid "EXIST" operator (for meta_query or tax_query), and prefer uses "IN" on IDs or key/value. I sometimes have "unexpected" results using it.